# Django not detecting model classes when folder named as Models

Tags: python, django

I splitted models into multiple files and placed them in a folder. Here is the tree structure. Mind the name of folder. It is 'Models' with capital M.

```
|-- Models
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- PersonModel.py
|   `-- VehicleModel.py
```

Content of `__init__.py` file is -

```
from .VehicleModel import *
from .PersonModel import *
```

I created a model class. Now when I am running `python manage.py makemigrations MyAppName` it says `No changes detected in app 'MyAppName'`

Things worked fine when I renamed folder form 'Models' to 'models'.

However I have done same for views i.e. splitted views into multiple files and placed in a folder. Tree structure is below.

```
`-- Views
    |-- DashboardView.py
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __pycache__
    |   |-- DashboardView.cpython-34.pyc
    |   |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    |   `-- VehicleView.cpython-34.pyc
    `-- VehicleView.py
```

Here folder name is 'Views' with capital V and things are working fine. No complaining by django.

I am not able to understand why makemigrations is not detecting the model classes when placed in folder named as Models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django doesn't know or care where your views are. You could put them in a folder called "thesearedefinitelynotviews" and it'll still work, as long as you imported them from there.

Models are different. Django needs to be able to find them on startup, so it can do things like set the relationships up correctly. In order for that to happen, they have to be accessible by importing `models`.

Comment: what is the better way to split models. (1) the way I did in question above or (2) import all models in a file models.py placed directly in app directory.
models.py will contain 'from Models/VehicleModel.py import *'

Comment: Also if I am importing like this -> 'from Models/VehicleModel import *' in models.py file , it throws error -> Invalid syntax ... carrot symbol pointing to slash